How to detect Oculus Quest controller rotates over 30 degrees to UP
could you please help me? I want to detect when an Oculus Quest 2 controller rotates around its axis towards the player by 30 degrees in 0.5 seconds. If the controller rotates in less time and by a smaller angle, it should not trigger.
As shown in the picture in the green rectangle.
I get controller rotation with
InputActionProperty _rightRotationAction;
InputActionProperty _leftRotationAction;

Thank you!

